# Tax_class_id per product (through SQL)

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql, tax-class

hoping you are well, I need your help with the following topic:

I want to make a report that **extracts all the products** in MAGENTO that **does NOT** have **tax_class_id = '2'** (taxable goods) and although I found the record in **catalog_product_index_price**, it only shows me the active products or with **inventory greater than zero**.
How can I get the **tax_class_id** of **inactive products** (with SQL)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
SELECT cs.`product_id`,cs.`qty`,
       cpi.`entity_id`,cpi.`tax_class_id` 
FROM cataloginventory_stock_item cs 
INNER JOIN catalog_product_index_price as cpi 
ON cs.product_id=cpi.`entity_id` 
WHERE cs.qty=0 AND cpi.tax_class_id=2;
```